# How to execute function with IF statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please help me and tell me how to execute function with IF statement? I am beginner with Javascript (using jQuery) and I can't find any tutorial which would be easy enough for me.

```
    var prvni;

    function druhy() {
        prvni = setTimeout(treti, 1250);
    }

    function treti() {
        $('.domovprostredninadpis').fadeOut(5000);
    }

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        if ($(this).scrollTop()>= $('#zonaobsahu').offset().top) {
            function druhy();
        }

    });
```

I want to make div '.domovprostredninadpis' to fade out in 5 seconds after I get to the '#zonaobsahu' (delay 1250ms before 'domovprostredninadpis' starts to fade out).

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: just remove function keyword. call this way - `druhy();`

Comment: @Akshay Thank you. Solved ;)

Comment: " I can't find any tutorial which would be easy enough for me." if you don't see the difference between function declaration and function call you will have all the possible problems while you develop in any language. Try to find a good reference like MDN (Mozilla developer network).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the line function druhy(); to druhy();

```
var prvni;

function druhy() {
    prvni = setTimeout(treti, 1250);
}

function treti() {
    $('.domovprostredninadpis').fadeOut(5000);
}

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>= $('#zonaobsahu').offset().top) {
        druhy();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Just change the line `function druhy();` to `druhy();` and add `clearTimeout(prvni);`

```
var prvni;

function druhy() {
    prvni = setTimeout(treti, 1250);
}

function treti() {
    $('.domovprostredninadpis').fadeOut(5000);
}

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#zonaobsahu').offset().top) {
        /* You should clear timeout before setting again */
        clearTimeout(prvni);
        druhy();
    }

});
```